# Perform a multilplication action on a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multiplication

I have an array full of string, the array is going to be used to create a CSV file from the array elements, but before I dump the values into a CSV file I need to perform some multiplication on some elements. For example I need to multiply the value "20" in array[0] by another value say "100"in array[1].

Anyone have any tips on where to begin. I'm totally new to Java, so please go gentle on me.

Thanks

Comment: i dont know about how to dump data in CSV but you can multiply your string array values after converting them into int with  `int a=Integer.parseInt(stringValue);`

Comment: Use some readily available JAR file for the CSV intricacies (escaping ...), e.g. http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

Comment: You can do something like `int a = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * Integer.parseInt(array[1]);`

Answer (score 2):

`Strings` can't be multiplied. They only get concatenated.

If you need to perform integer multiplication, you first need to cast `String` to integer and then multiply.

**Example Code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] arr = {"20", "30", "100"};

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);

        System.out.println(num1 * num2);
}
```

**Output**

```
2000
```

Comment: To add to this, you may want to write another function to check isNumeric either using Regular Expressions or some other method. If you do not you will encounter an exception when parsing the array values that are non-numeric. Eg: `String[] arr = {"20", "30", "100p"};` will fail due to an Exception while parsing `100p`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, I would do the following:

```
int value = array[0] * array[1]
```

Not sure if your array is made up of integers or another type (say Strings, depends where you got the values from. If you needed to multiple specific values together, you could do something like this:

```
for (int = 0; i < 50; i++){
    value = array[i] * array[i + 10]
```

Now that specific example would only work if you knew that you were going to multiple the xth position in the array, and then the 10th position after that. That being said, I'm sure you could use different loops to work out which two values needed multiplying together (as long as it's not just random, and your array has some form of logical structure to it).

Comment: It'll throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in case when `i>=40`. Such is not a good option.

Comment: Good point - it was just an example of what could be done, obviously it should be approached differently but that was just a thought :)